# Stuck at Continue? [y/n] in Jupiter Notebook

Tags: python, download, jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupiter Notebook online.
However, with the following line of code

```
!python3 scripts/download_weights.py
```

I remain stuck at:

```
About to download the pretrained weights file from https://www.dropbox.com/s/q8lax9ary32c7t9/pytorch_model.bin?dl=0#
The size of the file is roughly 85MB. Continue? [y/n]
```

I tried using --yes or --y at the end of the line but no luck.

Comment: is your pc almost full?

Comment: no. The issue is that I have no way to say yes. The last line you see is the output.

Comment: Can you try `! yes | python3 scripts/download_weights.py`

Comment: @AshlinJP works perfectly, If you post it as an answer I will close the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try [yes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/102484) command

```
! yes | python3 scripts/download_weights.py
```